# Ionic Unit Tests With Jasmine & Karma Getting Error (Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.002 secs / 0 secs))

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework

Try to run sample ionic tabs app using Unit testing of  Jasmine & Karma Getting Error Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.002 secs / 0 secs)) After execution of karma start unit-tests.conf.js

**Testing controller of test case :**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {   // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called   // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.   // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),   // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:   //   //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {   //});

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();   $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);   }; })

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats,$state, $ionicPopup) {   $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId); })

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {   $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true   }; });
```

**App controller :**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  };
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats,$state, $ionicPopup) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

Please help how for solve this.

Thanks in Advance,
Lokesh Patel